# How to order by a column (which match a criteria) in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different columns as DateTime type : CREATION_DATE and UPDATE_DATE

I want to create a SELECT (some fields) statement which order by the column (`UPDATE_DATE` or `CREATION_DATE` not both) where `UPDATE_DATE > CREATION_DATE` and `UPDATE_DATE` must be `NOT NULL`

Why ? Any items will be create in DB and `CREATION_DATE` will be filled automatically but not `UPDATE_DATE` column.

When somebody modify an existing item then the `UPDATE_DATE` will be filled/updated at every modification and will be listed on UserInterface by UPDATE_DATE (ascendent).

How to do that ?

Sorry if my question is bad ...

Comment: The question is general one. No code needed. I needed some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isnull`, if `UPDATE_DATE` is null it uses `CREATION_DATE` to order rows.

```
select * 
from table
order by isnull(UPDATE_DATE, CREATION_DATE) asc
```

Read more about [`isnull` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

[`coalesce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) is an alternative and it's going to work in most RDBMS (afaik).

```
select * 
from table
order by coalesce(UPDATE_DATE, CREATION_DATE) asc
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(UPDATE_DATE DATETIME,CREATION_DATE DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT '2011-01-01','2011-02-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2012-01-01','2011-12-10'

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
ORDER BY
    (
    CASE WHEN tbl.UPDATE_DATE>tbl.CREATION_DATE
        THEN tbl.UPDATE_DATE
        ELSE tbl.CREATION_DATE
    END) ASC
```

Comment: Yeah you have to be fast haha

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    *
from
(
    SELECT
        your_columns,
        ISNULL(UPDATE_DATE, CREATION_DATE) as sort_date
    FROM
        ....
)
order by
    sort_date
```

This selects the `UPDATE_DATE` column as `sort_date`. However, because of the `ISNULL` function, the column `CREATION_DATE` is used instead if `UPDATE_DATE` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to add a CASE column and order by it. I like this solution better because it  doesn't use sub-queries

```
select 
CASE
     WHEN UPDATE_DATE > CREATION_DATE THEN UPDATE_DATE 
     else CREATION_DATE 
END as MyOrderDate
, *
from fund_datasource_feed
order by MyOrderDate
```